# Get Specific PublicPort Endpoint in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, endpoints

I don't know how to Get specific VM's name and details with filter of PublicPort 80 Endpoint in Microsoft Azure Cloud

This is the closet command that I'd found in Google but the filtering part is missing.

**Get-AzureVM -ServiceName | Get-AzureEndpoint | Format-Table -AutoSize**

Thanks
Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic powershell. Use a Where-Object (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx).

i.e. Get-AzureEndpoint | Where-Object {$_.PublicPort -eq 80}

Comment: thanks it works now to me :-) !!! You know how can I get the VM name from the Get-AzureEndpoint because I have few servers on the same Cloud Service and I don't know who use this port ?